# Make keybinding for Reanalyze Sources in Dart Editor

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I'm running the dart editor version 0.6.15_r25822 and I like to make a Keybinding for "Reanalyze Sources".

I have exported the keybindingsfile and added this line after command "Quick Switch editor" and before command "Redo"

```xml
<keyBinding commandName="Reanalyze Sources" keySequence="F11"/>
```

and imported back in again, but it doesn't work for me.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it not possible yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in the editor, you won't be able to bind something to a key unless it's already bound to one. You can really just change existing keybindings, not add new ones.

And specifically for this menu item, I think our best solution is to make analysis more reliable. We don't want the 'Reanalyze Sources' command to be something that the user has to call frequently, or at all really. We are working on tightening up analysis as we approach the M6 release. Hope this helps -